# How to build a variation table with tkz-tab?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-tab

TikZ: variable in calc syntaTikZ: variable in calc syntax 1
x 1
[image]

Comment: Since you flagged with `tkz-tab` what have you already tried?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 13):

A quick tutorial to make a variation table with the `tkz-tab` package. If you want supplements say so.

### Initialization of the table: `\tkzTabInit`

For example the first braces define the data in the left column of the table, the second braces define the data in the first row of the second column. (example from tkz-tab manual)

```
\tikz \tkzTabInit{$x$ /.8 , $f(x)$ /.8}{$0$ , $+\infty$};
```

[image: tkz-tab-1]

In these two columns:

- the rows are separated by commas.
- The first line is defined by `$x$`. The slash `/` separator separates the contents of the line from its height. Thus, here, both lines have a height of `0.8`.

To obtain a three-line table, write:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzTabInit{$x$ /1,
            $f'(x)$ /1,
            $f(x)$ /1}% end of the first left column 
           {$-\infty$,$-2$,$0,$,$+\infty$} % first line of right column
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: image2]

### Add content with the `\tkzTabLine` macro

To add the data from the second line, we'll use the `\tkzTabLine`

- `z` places a dotted line and a zero centered
- `t` places a dotted line centered
- `d` places a double centered bar

example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\begin{document}
\tkzTabInit{$x$ /1,$f'(x)$ /1,$f(x)$ /2}
           {$-\infty$,$-2$,$0$,$+\infty$}
\tkzTabLine{,+,z,-,z,-}
\end{document}
```

Output :

[image: tkz-tab-3]

### Add the variation line with `\tkztabVar` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand*{ \E}{ \ensuremath{ \mathrm{e}}}.
\tkzTabInit{$x$ /1,$f'(x)$ /1,$f(x)$ /2}
{$-\infty$,$-2$,$0$,$+\infty$}
\tkzTabLine{,+,z,-,z,-}
\tkzTabVar{-/$-\infty$,
            +/$2$,
            R/,
            -/$-\infty$}
\tkzTabIma{2}{4}{3}{$0$}            
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: tkz-tab-4]

the `\tkzTabIma` macro is used to position a value on a variation arrow   `\tkzTabIma[ 〈 local options 〉 ]{Beginning}{End}{Position}{Back}{Image}`

- `Beginning` rank of arrow origin
- `End`  rank of arrow end
- `Position` rank of the antecedent corresponding to the image
- `Image` image value if necessary

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator