# i'm having hard time making tables of variations in latex

Tags: tables

i'm writing my thesis and i face these two tables of variations, please help me transfer them to latex. 
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not show any effort.

Comment: Among the packages I know, you may take a look at the `tableaux` package (based on `pstricks`) and `tikz-tab`, based on `tikz`.

Comment: this is the code i used (i tried to replace the cos and sin by f and f prime but it didn't work )

Comment: \begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzTab{$x$ / 1 , $\cos(x)$ / 1, $\sin(x)$ / 1.5}{$0$, $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, $\pi$}
          {, +, z, -, }
          {-/ 0, +/ 1, -/ 0}
\end{tikzpicture}

Comment: guys this is my first time to ask here all the time i try to solve my issus by searching but this one i didn't found anything similer and also i'm new to latex (i will have my thesis on this Friday )

Comment: The answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447164/how-to-build-a-variation-table-with-tkz-tab) might help.